# Download Audio File From Url To Storage And Play On Download Complete In Codename One

Tags: codenameone

I am developing an application using codenameone that needs to download an audio file (mp3)
from a remote server, and then play it once the download is complete.

I want it to happen once a button is clicked, but so far...all i see in the simulator is the  infinite dialog and nothing else.

I am using java 7 on my development pc.

Here are relevant code snippets:

```
          ok.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        String file=_cat+".mp3";
        String path="/"+file;
        Util.downloadUrlToStorage("http://abcde.com/images/"+file,path,true);

       final InputStream is = Display.getInstance().getResourceAsStream(this.getClass(), path);
    try {
      Media  mm = MediaManager.createMedia(is, "audio/mp3");
        mm.play();
    } 
    catch (IOException ex) {
       ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
          });
```

How can i get to download the audio file and play it once it completes?.
I edited my code in line with shai almog's answer, to the following:

```
          ok.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
               String file=_cat+".mp3";
        Util.downloadUrlToStorage("http://abcde.com/images/"+file,file,true);


        try {
            is = Storage.getInstance().createInputStream(file);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
           ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    try {
      Media  mm = MediaManager.createMedia(is, "audio/mp3");
        mm.play();
    } 
    catch (IOException ex) {
       ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

....and still nothing gets downloaded....i go to the

```
         .CodenameOneStorage
```

directory on my PC but nothing there..i guess
i am missing something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getResourceAsStream` returns a stream into a jar and is a read only path. Its not a "file" and you can't write there. Storage is a simplified file system that is unrelated to that either.

You can use something like:

```
Util.downloadUrlToStorage("http://abcde.com/images/"+file,file,true);
InputStream is = Storage.getInstance().createInputStream(file);
```

Comment: You can use the network monitor tool in the simulator to see what is going on. Storage is under .cn1 not .CodenameOneStorage