# how to get audio from URL in codename one also i need audio timer

Tags: codenameone

how to get audio from  URL in codename one and also i need audio current timer ?

i refer this link: [Download Audio File From Url To Storage And Play On Download Complete In Codename One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31183793/download-audio-file-from-url-to-storage-and-play-on-download-complete-in-codenam/31198216#31198216)

Comment: The question is very unclear, what's the problem with the answer given there and what doesn't work?